# Define simple color for both draw and fill

Tags: color

I would like to define a simple (not RGB) color and use it for both drawing and filling:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{mycolor/.style={color=black!45}}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[mycolor] (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
\draw[fill=mycolor] (2,2) rectangle (3,3);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

However, when I use it for filling (the second square), I get

```
! Package xcolor Error: Undefined color `mycolor'.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could define a new colour using `\colorlet`:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\colorlet{mycolor}{black!45}

\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[mycolor] (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
\draw[fill=mycolor] (2,2) rectangle (3,3);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]